# Views Row Style - Fields vs. Teaser?

Tags: views, 6

What is better for performance in views, using fields or a teaser view?  Assuming you would be adding all fields necessary for it to look just like the teaser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields option is generally faster, because it performs only 1 database query (2 if there's a pager in use).  The teaser display requires a node_load(), which causes numerous hooks to fire and many more queries.