# Views performance: Teaser vs Fields

Tags: 7, views, performance

I have to create a view on a Drupal 7 site which will have 6/8 node fields. There will be some logic for which I will have to rewrite results as well as create a *views-view-field-XX.tpl.php* template file.

Thus, instead of using fields, using *Content > Teaser* and writing/reusing the logic in the *node--CONTENT-TYPE.tpl.php* template file looks more tempting to me. It also seems to make my work easier.

I am worried that using *Content > Teaser* will impact the performance because, with fields, only the required fields will be loaded, whereas, with *Content > Teaser*, the complete node will be loaded.

1. If I have set only 2-4 fields for the *Teaser mode* in *Manage display*, will the view still load the complete node?
2. In the case the view loads the complete node, does it harm performance? [Views Row Style - Fields vs. Teaser?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6201/views-row-style-fields-vs-teaser) and [Fields vs. Teaser/Node view](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_views/issues/1205652) say it does impact performance, but they apply to Drupal 6.

Comment: You can probably easily check this out yourself by having a local copy of your site, try both approaches and then check the performance tab in your browser's developer tools. I'd always go for view modes. Views fields are much harder to maintain in the long run, especially for markup changes. View modes provide more consistent UI and clearer templates.